# Pseudocode Sum & Division Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, sum, division, pseudocode

"Given a list L of n numbers, take the sum of absolute values divided by the number of elements in L." How can I do this?

This is what I have so far

```
start
Get values for list L and n
INDEX = 1
while (INDEX ≤ n) do
    Read: n;
    Set sum = 0;
    for i = 1 to n by 1 do
        Set sum = sum + i
```

Comment: So what is your concrete problem?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear - whether n is known prior L

```
read n
read n values in L

sum = 0
for i = 1 to n by 1 do   //assuming 1-based list indexing
   sum = sum + Abs(L[i])
av = sum / n
```

Comment: Once I have the sum, how would I divide it by the # of elements in the list?

Comment: The last line does it